# cant find a way for my code to scan how many integers were inputted to set array length and to have it set those integers in an array

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.*;

public class Commission {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter sales amount separated by space:");
    double[] saleAmounts = Inputs(input);
}
```

*Below is where my function scans numbers, but I need it to scan an x amount of values entered 'at the same time' to set the array length. Also, I need it so the user only enters in values once*

(i have the length at 5 for a logic test)

```
private static double[] Inputs(Scanner sc) {   
    double[] sales = new double[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < sales.length; i++){
        sales[i] = sc.nextDouble();
    }
    return sales;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Array is a data structure with set size. If you want to have dynamic sized 'array', use List or ArrayList for example.

Answer (score 0):

From the user, read an entire **line** (they enter values separated by spaces and hit enter), then pass that to your method and split it on space.

Something like: **no exception checking included**

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter sales amounts separated by spaces, then hit Enter: ");    
    double[] saleAmounts= Inputs(input.nextLine());
    for(int i=0; i < saleAmounts.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("index " + i + " : " + saleAmounts[i]);
    }
}

private static double[] Inputs(String inputLine) 
{   

    String[] values = inputLine.split(" ");
    double[] sales = new double[values.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
    {
        sales[i] = Double.parseDouble(values[i]);
    }    
    return sales;
}
```